# Agregué un campo extra al modelo y arrojó este error: System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException

Tags: c#, linq, excepciones

Ocupo el nuevo campo que agregué, pero me sale error en la estructura del modelo, que puedo hacer?

```
      public void AgregarOrdenS(Orden_Servicio os, string BD)
    {

        try
        {
            var context = new MODELO.Entity(BD);
            context.Orden_Servicio.Add(os);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }           
        catch (System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException  ex)
        {
            var inner = ex.InnerException.InnerException;

            throw;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Buenas, en qué momento declaras la variable "os"?

Comment: Una disculpa, al declarar la funcion :public void AgregarOrdenS(Orden_Servicio os, string BD)

Comment: hiciste un update de la base de datos?

Comment: No hice update, no quiero agregar a la BD un campo, simplemente lo quiero usar para consulta

Comment: Supongo que por el modelo no se puede hacer eso...

Comment: deberias crear un dto para ese modelo y luego de realizar la logica mapear dicho dto a la entidad para dar de alta. Claro que la entidad no deberia tener una propiedad que no usas en la bd, eso seria la funcion del dto.

Comment: si la agregaste al modelo, al hacer save esta esperando grabarla en la base de datos y de ahi el error.

Comment: @WFgo Si, creare un dto para dar de alta, muchisimas gracias!

Comment: @gbianchi si, ese es el error, quería saber como hacerlo de otra manera... creare un dto para dar de alta.. muchas gracias por tu ayuda!